# Unable to assign the elements of a split string into variables

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm building a name splitter for a regular task we have a work. I'm trying to get it to split a string (someones full name) into the individual names, then paste those individual names into new cells on the sheet. This is as far as I've got:

```
Sub nameSorter()

Dim nameArray As Variant
Dim namA As String
Dim namB As String
Dim namC As String
Dim namD As String
Dim namSplit() As String
Dim rowNum, spaceCount, namNum As Integer

nameArray = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("A3:A50"))
        
For Each nam In nameArray
    rowNum = nameArray(nam).row
    namSplit = Split(nam, " ")
    namNum = UBound(namSplit)
    If namNum = 4 Then
        namA = namSplit(0)
        namB = namSplit(1)
        namC = namSplit(2)
        namD = namSplit(3)
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("B" & rowNum) = namA.Value
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("C" & rowNum) = namB.Value
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("D" & rowNum) = namC.Value
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("E" & rowNum) = namD.Value
    ElseIf namNum = 3 Then
        namA = namSplit(0)
        namB = namSplit(1)
        namC = namSplit(2)
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("B" & rowNum) = namA.Value
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("C" & rowNum) = namB.Value
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("D" & rowNum) = namC.Value
    ElseIf namNum = 2 Then
        namA = namSplit(0)
        namB = namSplit(1)
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("B" & rowNum) = namA.Value
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("C" & rowNum) = namB.Value
    ElseIf namNum = 1 Then
        namA = namSplit(0)
        Worksheets("MegaSorter").Range("B" & rowNum) = namA.Value
    Else
    End If

Next nam
```

My array is populating and the namSplit is splitting the names as I want.

For some reason when I compile, it's saying my `namA` is not an invalid identifier. Looking at the documentation this means it doesn't point to anything but I'm defining these variables and filling them with the code just before it so I can't see the issue?

I did have it running with just 3 'nam' variables but I need 4, to catch anyone with 4 names (such as James Van Der Whal) as we have agents in countries where those kinds of names are pretty common.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: `namA` is a `String` - it doesn't have a Value property. (same with the others).

Comment: Some pointers: 1. Please Use `Option Explicit`. 2. `Dim rowNum, spaceCount, namNum As Integer` means that only `namNum` is of `Integer` data type. Other 2 are of type `Variant`. Change this to `Dim rowNum As Integer, spaceCount As Integer, namNum As Integer` (although i would highly recommend to declare them as `Long`). 3. Not sure why you have to assign values from an array to variables and then use the variables to assign further values. Just use the array to assign values straight to your worksheet. You don't need the `string` variables

Comment: `namNum` (`UBound(namSplit)`) would be 3 in case of an array with 4 elements. Lake you try in your code, it starts counting from zero... Only if you have `Option Base 1` on top of your module and that's why the problem with `namA = namSplit(0)`, too. This logic supposing that the error appears on this line. Otherwise, `namA.Value` is a "personal approach" for a string, which does not have such a property...

Comment: you could easily do this all in a loop instead of the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I hesitated to answer this post as there are number of similar questions at SO.
On the other hand a simple problem allows to demonstrate some
common issues united here *all together* and how to solve them by different approaches.

Therefore I try to modify your code in several steps
starting from an approach close to your OP.

**First step**

As mentioned in above comments, its necessary to declare each variable type separately or
VBA assumes it to be `Variant`. Therefore `rowNum` and `spaceCount` wouldn't be considered as `Integer` in `Dim rowNum, spaceCount, namNum As Integer`

Furthermore you are on the safe side using `Long`, especially for (range) counters; sheets with nowadays over 1M rows can exceed
integer limit (ending at 32,767) by far.

Always use `Option Explicit` to force variable declarations.

It's overcomplicating to define extra variables `namA` to `namC` if you could use
`namSplit(n)` directly.

A range has a `.Row` property, but you can't apply this to an *array*.

`UBound(namSplit)` returns the upper bound of an array; if it is zero-based you have to add `1` to get the number of items.

Always try to fully qualify your sheet references. You can use the sheet's Code(Name) of your current VBA project instead of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MegaSorter")` in a `With` - `End With` structure to shorten endless repetitions and to avoid typos. Code(Name) references might be useful to provide for manual sheet re-naming by other users.

```
Option Explicit             ' declaration head of your code module

Sub nameSorterCloseToOP()

Dim nameArray As Variant
Dim namA As String
Dim namB As String
Dim namC As String
Dim namD As String
Dim namSplit() As String
Dim rowNum As Long, spaceCount As Long, namNum As Long  ' declare each type separately
With Sheet1                             ' using the sheet's Code(Name)
    Dim rng As Range                    ' define data range
    Set rng = .Range("A3:A50")
    'assign data to "flat" 1-dim array
    nameArray = Application.Transpose(rng)
            
    Dim nam As Variant                  ' declare nam as Variant type
    rowNum = rng.Row                    ' define start row as top row of range
    For Each nam In nameArray
        namSplit = Split(nam, " ")
        'count right number of array items (usually you get a zero-based split array)
        namNum = UBound(namSplit) - LBound(namSplit) + 1 ' general rule for any array base
        If namNum = 4 Then
            namA = namSplit(0)
            namB = namSplit(1)
            namC = namSplit(2)
            namD = namSplit(3)
            .Range("B" & rowNum) = namA
            .Range("C" & rowNum) = namB
            .Range("D" & rowNum) = namC
            .Range("E" & rowNum) = namD
        ElseIf namNum = 3 Then
            namA = namSplit(0)
            namB = namSplit(1)
            namC = namSplit(2)
            .Range("B" & rowNum) = namA
            .Range("C" & rowNum) = namB
            .Range("D" & rowNum) = namC
        ElseIf namNum = 2 Then
            namA = namSplit(0)
            namB = namSplit(1)
            .Range("B" & rowNum) = namA
            .Range("C" & rowNum) = namB
        ElseIf namNum = 1 Then
            namA = namSplit(0)
            .Range("B" & rowNum) = namA
        Else
        End If
    
        'increment rowNum
         rowNum = rowNum + 1
    
    Next nam

End With
End Sub
```

**Code refined**

In order to avoid a complicated count of tokens in the `namSplit` array it's possible
to split full names into **exactly** 4 tokens including empty ones (see section `a`)
by joining *`blanks`* to each item before splitting.

It's possible as well to write array
values to a target range by one single code line (see section `b`: `.Range("B" & i + rowOffset).Resize(, maxItems) = namSplit`)

```
Sub nameSorterRefined()
Const maxItems As Long = 4
Dim nameArray  As Variant
Dim namSplit() As String
Dim Blanks     As String
Blanks = String(maxItems - 1, " ")      ' string with 4-1 blanks
With Sheet1             ' using the sheet's Code(Name)
    Dim rng As Range                    ' define data range
    Set rng = .Range("A3:A50")
    'assign data to "flat" 1-dim array
    nameArray = Application.Transpose(rng)
    
    Dim rowOffset As Long
    rowOffset = rng.Row - 1             ' start row as top row of range minus 1
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(nameArray)      ' 1-based, as transposed range data field
        'a) split nameArray into exactly 4 tokens, even empty ones
        namSplit = Split(nameArray(i) & Blanks, " ")
        'b) write items back to sheet
        .Range("B" & i + rowOffset).Resize(, maxItems) = namSplit
    Next i

End With
End Sub
```

**Array approach only**

Alternatively it's possible to write all names to a predefined datafield array with four columns (see section `a` to `b`)
and write them back in one line (see section `c`).

```
Sub nameSorterArray()
    Const maxColumns As Long = 4
'a) assign data to variant 1-based 2-dim ("vertical") array
    Dim nameArray As Variant
    nameArray = Sheet1.Range("A3:A50")     ' get data referring to sheet's Code(Name)
    'make it a 4-column array (with data in its 1st column)
    '(note that you can only redimension the array's last! dimension)
    ReDim Preserve nameArray(1 To UBound(nameArray), 1 To maxColumns)
    
'b) write names to four columns array (overwriting full names in array's 1st column)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, names
    For i = 1 To UBound(nameArray)          ' loop through full names
        names = Split(nameArray(i, 1), " ") ' split into names (gets 0-based 1-dim array)
        For j = 1 To UBound(names) + 1      ' add 1 to max 4 names to array columns
            nameArray(i, j) = names(j - 1)  ' names indices are zero-based, hence j minus 1
        Next j
    Next i

'c) write results to any target range
    Sheet1.Range("B3").Resize(UBound(nameArray), maxColumns) = nameArray
End Sub
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: @TomCrow Did you find my post helpful? - If so feel free to accept by ticking the green checkmark to mark the answer as accepted; helps other users, too :-)